# how can I "shell programming" in launch file?

Tags: ros, shell

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
I alwasy run some command in terminal like:

```
sudo chmod 777 /dev/USB0
sudo chmod 777 /dev/ACM0
```

but how can i do this in launch file, when i ask `roslaunch expamle.launch` it call this shell programming for once?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63813/how-can-i-%22shell-programming%22-in-launch-file?/) by [Mohsen Hk](https://answers.ros.org/users/4097/mohsen-hk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 139 on 2013-05-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should really configure your system so that you don't have to manually modify device permissions on startup.

For serial devices on most Linux systems, that usually just means adding yourself to the proper group that has access to the serial device, or modifying the udev rules.

You can verify which group has access to the devices by doing `ls -l /dev/ttyACM0 /dev/ttyUSB0` ; then add yourself to that group. For example, on Ubuntu the group is `dialout`, so you would do:

```
sudo usermod -a -G dialout USER
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2013-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [koenlek](https://answers.ros.org/users/4402/koenlek/) on 2014-04-24**:
Please note that you need to log-out and log-in again (or reboot your pc) for this changes to take efffect! After that, it works like a charm here...

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Put these commands into an [executable shell script](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_01.html) (let's call it `yourscript.sh`) somewhere inside the package directory (let's call the package `yourpackage`) and then reference that script inside your launch file (e.g. `example.launch`):

```
<node name="nodename" pkg="yourpackage" type="yourscript.sh">
```

---

Originally posted by [DamienJadeDuff](https://answers.ros.org/users/2651/damienjadeduff/) with karma: 399 on 2013-05-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2013-05-28**:
Actually `roslaunch direct_path_to_.launch_file` *is* possible. See `roslaunch -h` ;-)

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2013-05-28**:
@Mohsen Keep in mind that this 'script node' is started with all others in parallel. So while usually the *chmod*s will be done before any node even starts thinking about those */dev*s, the worst case might be that every other node has started (and perhaps crashed) before the first *chmod* is called

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-05-29**:\

- For sudo, you'd need to enter password. From the command, it seems you should set that up with udev. For the devices you use, it might also be sufficient to do `adduser <USER> dialout`.

**Comment by [benabruzzo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2641/benabruzzo/) on 2014-04-14**:
When I use the above  I get an error: ERROR: cannot launch node of type [hast/yourScript.sh]: Cannot locate node of type [yourScript.sh] in package [hast].  Is an entry to the CMakeLists file necessary?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-04-15**:
Is the script executable?

**Comment by [DamienJadeDuff](https://answers.ros.org/users/2651/damienjadeduff/) on 2014-04-17**:
Fixed the answer, thanks felix k. My answer is not a good one anyway. ;)